# What is the point of initializing a base class object as a derived class object

Tags: class, interface, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

If I want to initialize a class `Square`

```
class Square : public Rectangle {
    public Square(int length)
    {
        this->length = length;
        this->width = length;
    }
}
```

derived from a class `Rectangle`

```
class Rectangle {
    protected int length, width;

    public Rectangle(int length, int width)
    {
        this->length = length;
        this->width = width;
    }

    public int getArea() { return length * width; }
}
```

I'll do it like

```
Square * s = new Square(5);
cout << s->getArea() << endl;
```

---

What are the benefits of doing it like

```
Rectangle * r = new Square(5);
cout << r->getArea() << endl;
```

instead and initializing the object as a base class object?

Comment: Search for inheritance in object oriented languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an *interface* and an *implementation* of that interface. This is part of how **inheritance** and **polymorphism** work together.

`Rectangle *r = new Square` works only if `Square` derives from `Rectangle`.  Any object that is a `Rectangle` descendant can be assigned to a `Rectangle*` pointer.

Say all your code needs is a `Rectangle*` pointer to do its work.  The code doesn't need to care whether it operates on a `Square` object in memory.  Perhaps you have to make that decision based on user input at run-time, or certain business rules, etc.  Polymorphism allows that.  The *interface* ensures that the needed `Rectangle` functionality is available, and how to use it.  The compiler takes care of delegating to the *implementation* accordingly.